# Fetch details by order id

Tags: forms, woocommerce, billing

I have set up a proper invoicing system for my e-commerce platform and hence we record all the orders in the platform. I don't have issue with online orders, but there are cases when we book offline orders and customer repeats the order. In this case, right now, I have to copy and paste old order details manually.

I was trying to write code which will add an option to fetch billing details of old order by order id in WooCommerce new order form. This will be used only by admin and shop managers. My code is adding an option to fetch details but unfortunately, details are not getting fetched in the new order form.

```
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('custom_meta_box', 'Copy Billing Details from Previous Order', 'custom_meta_box_callback', 'shop_order', 'side', 'default');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');

function custom_meta_box_callback() {
    ?>
    <div>
        <label for="order_number">Order Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="order_number" name="order_number" />
        <button id="fetch_billing_details">Fetch</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#fetch_billing_details').click(function() {
                var order_number = $('#order_number').val();
                if (order_number == '') {
                    alert('Please enter an order number.');
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
                        data: {
                            action: 'fetch_billing_details',
                            order_number: order_number
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            if (response == '-1') {
                                alert('Invalid order number. Please try again.');
                            } else {
                                var billing_details = $.parseJSON(response);
                                $('#billing_first_name').val(billing_details.billing_first_name);
                                $('#billing_last_name').val(billing_details.billing_last_name);
                                $('#billing_company').val(billing_details.billing_company);
                                $('#billing_address_1').val(billing_details.billing_address_1);
                                $('#billing_address_2').val(billing_details.billing_address_2);
                                $('#billing_city').val(billing_details.billing_city);
                                $('#billing_state').val(billing_details.billing_state);
                                $('#billing_postcode').val(billing_details.billing_postcode);
                                $('#billing_country').val(billing_details.billing_country);
                                $('#billing_email').val(billing_details.billing_email);
                                $('#billing_phone').val(billing_details.billing_phone);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_billing_details', 'fetch_billing_details_callback');
function fetch_billing_details_callback() {
    $order_number = $_POST['order_number'];
    $order = wc_get_order($order_number);
    if ($order) {
        $billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $billing_company = $order->get_billing_company();
        $billing_address_1 = $order->get_billing_address_1();
        $billing_address_2 = $order->get_billing_address_2();
        $billing_city = $order->get_billing_city();
        $billing_state = $order->get_billing_state();
        $billing_postcode = $order->get_billing_postcode();
        $billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
        $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
        $billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
        
        $billing_details = array(
            'billing_first_name' => $billing_first_name,
            'billing_last_name' => $billing_last_name,
            'billing_company' => $billing_company,
            'billing_address_1' => $billing_address_1,
            'billing_address_2' => $billing_address_2,
            'billing_city' => $billing_city,
            'billing_state' => $billing_state,
            'billing_postcode' => $billing_postcode,
            'billing_country' => $billing_country,
            'billing_email' => $billing_email,
            'billing_phone' => $billing_phone
        );
        echo json_encode($billing_details);
    } else {
        echo '-1';
    }
    wp_die();
}
```